# Python Smartsheet SDK Issue - Cannot Import Smartsheet with API Token

Tags: python, sdk

I am trying to use Python to update a test data sheet in Smartsheet.

In Python:

```
import smartsheet
smartsheet_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet('###############')
```

```
Error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\smartsheet\smartsheet.py", line 154, in __init__

  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\smartsheet\session.py", line 53, in pinned_session
    pool_connections=4,
AttributeError: type object 'Retry' has no attribute 'DEFAULT_METHOD_WHITELIST'
```

The error I'm getting isn't helpful.  I can't figure out what I am doing wrong or don't have setup properly.

I am hoping to update smartsheet automatically using Python, but I can't get my API token to work.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by installing the newest version of Python.  See below for details.

Older version:  3.10

New version:  3.12